# RXJS BehaviourSubject alternative for Blazor-WASM to Store and manage data from a REST data source

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've developed some applications in the past using Angular and RxJs BehaviourSubject to share data between components. I'm migrating some applications to Blazor-WASM. The main idea is here to only once call an API endpoint and store the results in some (singleton) store. The data store maintains one copy of an entity list (also supports CRUD operations) and notifies observing components/pages of changes in the data structure. The singleton scope mentioned here is scoped to the client's browser.

So far I can't find a way to make this work. I think my main issue here is that Services.AddHttpClient registeres HttpClient factories as transient scoped and therefore cannot be injected in a singleton scoped store.

Wat would be a Blazor architecture to achieve something similar?